# The interior of the rational numbers topological space is empty

Tags: general-topology

I do not quite understand why the interior of the rational numbers topological space is empty, here is my reasoning.

1. $\mathbb{Q}$ can be regarded as a subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology, this means that an open set in $\mathbb{Q}$ will be in the form of $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ [of course $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\emptyset$ are also open sets in $\mathbb{Q}$].
2. If $int(\mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset$, then there should not exist an element $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that there exists an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $x$.
3. But, given $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, we can pick any real open interval $(c,d)$ containing $x$, then $(c,d) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $x$ with being a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, so $x \in int(\mathbb{Q})$ and $int(\mathbb{Q}) \neq \emptyset$.

I am sure some part of my reasoning has to be incorrect, could anyone kindly point it out?

Comment: The interior of $\mathbb{Q}$ is empty with respect to the topology in $\mathbb{R}$. With respect to the subspace topology on $\mathbb{Q}$, the interior of $\mathbb{Q}$ is itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This essentially involves distinguishing subsets from subspaces.
The interior of $\mathbb{Q}$ is **not** empty when $\mathbb{Q}$ is interpreted as the "parent space". Indeed, if $(X,\mathfrak{T})$ is any topological space, then the interior of $X$ (relative to itself) is the entire space $X$!

When we say that $\mathbb{Q}$ has empty interior, we mean that $\mathbb{Q}$ has empty interior as a *subset* of $\mathbb{R}$. In this case, the basis elements of the topology no longer have the form $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Instead, the basis elements take the form $(a,b)$ which will *always* contain a point in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for writing this concise explanation, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @James Anytime! Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

The correct statement is: interior of $\mathbb  Q$ in $\mathbb  R$ is empty. What you are saying is that interior of $\mathbb  Q$ in $\mathbb  Q$ is not empty, which is true but it does  not contradict the first statement.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I understand it now.